# Applying AngularJS material design styles to dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I have an `AngularJS` application where I have a requirement to add `AngularJS` material components dynamically. I'm using `Jquery` to do so using a button click.

The components are being added to the layout but the styles are not applying to it.

But there are other components which are loaded on page load looks totally fine.

Can someone help me out with this issue?? Thank you.

Here is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = $('#contactNum').val();
    $('#addEmergencyContact').click(function() {
        counter++;
        $('#contactNum').text(counter);
    $(this).before('<div class="card-body pt-0">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <md-input-container class="md-block mx-4 mt-4" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" ng-model="emergency_firstname" autocomplete="off" >
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block mx-4 mt-3" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>Surname</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" ng-model="emergency_lastname" autocomplete="off" >
        </md-input-container><md-input-container class="md-block mx-4 mt-3" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" ng-model="emergency_email" autocomplete="off" >
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block mx-4 mt-3" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" ng-model="emergency_phone" autocomplete="off" >
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block mx-4 mt-3" md-theme="altTheme1"  flex-gt-sm>
            <label>Relationship to you</label>
            <md-select ng-model="relation" placeholder="Relationship" ng-selected="get_Selected_relation()" >
                <md-option value="Spouse">Spouse</md-option>
                <md-option value="Partner">Partner</md-option>
                <md-option value="Parent">Parent</md-option>
                <md-option value="Friend">Friend</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
    <button id="removeEmergencyContact">Remove Contact</button> 
  </div>');
  });

    $(document).on('click','#removeEmergencyContact',function() {
        counter--;
        $('#contactNum').text(counter);
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });  
});
```

Here is my AngularJS code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
app.controller('ParticipantController', function($scope) {

});
```

As of now, I haven't written anything for setting the values to the AngularJS components. So it's blank.

Here is the image

[image]

The upper portion of the image renders on load, and the lower portion of the image gets loaded when the add button is clicked.

Comment: Have you considered writing some code in angularjs?

Comment: Ya. I have written and updated my question with the code.

Comment: I strongly recommend not mixing AngularJS and jQuery like this. Both are DOM manipulation frameworks and they will not work well together. Pick one framework and stick with it.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I implement the same in AngularJS to have components dynamically on click of a button??

Comment: @Prabhu I'm facing the same problem. Were you able to figure out a solution for this? Could you please share it?

Comment: @Sunny, please refer to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504227/add-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click-using-angular-js`. It helped me in solving my problem.

Comment: @Sunny, if you find the solution helpful please upvote my accept answer to help the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a solution from the past few weeks. Finally, @Rayon's solution helped me to solve it.

Anyone who is facing the same problem and looking for the solution can follow this post.

**[add form fields dynamically on user click using angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504227/add-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click-using-angular-js).**

Hope it helps. Thank you.